# How to create template helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, helper, discourse

I want to create `eq` helper. It already exists in `ember-truth-helpers` addon, but I need only `eq` helper so I decided create it by myself in my plugin.

I've created file `assets/javascripts/discourse/helpers/eq.js.es6` in my plugin with such content:

```
import { registerHelper } from 'discourse/lib/helpers';

registerHelper('eq', function(params) {
  return params[0] === params[1];
});
```

and use it in template in this way:

```
{{#if (eq param1 param2)}} <h1>hello</h1> {{/if}}
```

But `eq` is not defined.

What is the right way to create helper?

Comment: are you using ember-cli?

Comment: @wallop im not using ember-cli

Comment: Which version of Ember are you using?

Comment: @locks, ember 1.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the bounding. This code works for me:

```
import { registerHelper } from 'discourse/lib/helpers';

var makeBoundHelper = Ember.HTMLBars.makeBoundHelper;

registerHelper('eq', makeBoundHelper(function(params) {
  return params[0] === params[1];
}));
```

The solution is taken from [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10153)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are using ember-cli, if so kindly do go through generators in ember-cli guide

> ember g helper is-equal

will result in app/helpers/is-equal.js which will initially be

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function isEqual(params/*, hash*/) {
  return params;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(isEqual);
```

but you can change it to

```
export function isEqual([leftSide, rightSide, isCaseInsensitive]) {
  let ret;
  if (isCaseInsensitive) {
    ret = (leftSide.toLowerCase() === rightSide.toLowerCase());
  } else {
    ret = (leftSide === rightSide);
  }
  return ret;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(isEqual);
```

Now you can use it in your templates as

```
{{#if (is-equal 'abc' 'ABC' true)}}

{{/if}}
```